# How to add FontAwesome icon instead on text in php?

Tags: php, woocommerce, font-awesome

I'm trying replace string "Add to cart" with cart's icon. The question is how to insert font awesome icon`<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>` inside this php code:

```
$text = $this->is_purchasable() && $this->is_in_stock() ? __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );

return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', $text, $this );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't you just replace the "Add to cart" text with the icon?

Comment: How to do that? I'm trying to do this using code. Maybe there are some additional ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

St Pavel,

Not familiar with woocommerce but...

Did you try:

```
$text = $this->is_purchasable() && $this->is_in_stock() ? __( '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );
```

**EDIT:**

From your comment, it looks like apply_filters function does not accept HTML value as an arg, for it's second param. As such, here's what I recommend:

Most simplest approach is to use jQuery:

I looked at the demo here: https://demo.woothemes.com/storefront/shop/ inspected the "Add to cart" button... as far as `<a>` tag's class goes, the value is: `class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart fa fa-cart-plus"`

As such you can do either:

```
jQuery('a.ajax_add_to_cart').addClass('fa fa-cart-plus');
```

or

```
jQuery('a.add_to_cart_button').addClass('fa fa-cart-plus');
```

**EDIT #2:**

And since you are trying to replace the text with the icon (and not have icon AND text), do the following:

```
jQuery('a.ajax_add_to_cart').text('');
```

or

```
jQuery('a.add_to_cart_button').text('');
```

Hope this helps!

-Rush

Comment: I've tried that way, but no FontAwesom icon appeared, just pure html with FA code.

Comment: in that case, it looks like apply_filters() does not accept html value for it's second param. Anyway you can override this function? (**WITHOUT** hacking the core code?)

Comment: I've decided to use jQuery for that. The easiest way for me now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php

replace this

```
sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;%s</a>',
```